# Linux nodejs rest service work only localhost

Tags: node.js, linux, rest

i'm developing a REST API with node js on linux.
This my first sample code to try if all works fine:

```
'use strict';

var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080 ;

app.listen(port, "127.0.0.1", function(){
console.log("Express server is listening on port ", port);
});
```

i have try to call localhost:8080 into linux server and works fine.
If i try to call trhe IP of server with this port by a external IP the express server not responding.
Any help about this?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue unrelated to express. You could use a tool like localtunnel:
https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel

Comment: You're only listening on localhost... `"127.0.0.1"`.

Comment: If you call http://hostname:8080 on the server does that work? If it does then perhaps update the question with that information because there may have been more than 1 reason you could not get remote connectivity and the answers given so far resolve 1 of those reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second parameter to the `app.listen()` [api](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), which you set to "**127.0.0.1**" is the hostname.  This will cause node to only listen for requests matching that host name from the request domain.

This is an optional parameter.

Perhaps try the `app.listen(port, callback)` form of the api?

```
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Express server is listening on port ", port);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world!')
});
```

Or you can move the [hostname] parameter to a configuration file if you don't want your service to listen to *every* host name.

See the [server.listen()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) documentation for better insight into parameter default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this so your app listens on all network interfaces and not only on localhost:

```
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function(){
    console.log("Express server is listening on port ", port);
});
```

Comment: i have just try but the result is the same

Comment: Its a working code, may be your port is not publicly accessible is the problem